# How to specify which century a date should be parsed in Joda-Time

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, datetime-format

I have some HR records whose dates are formatted as `dd/MM/yy`, and I am normalizing them to `dd-MM-yyyy` using [`Joda-Time`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).
So for example, the following records are normalized as follows

```
  Input        Output
30/01/14 --> 30-01-2014
15/07/99 --> 15-07-1999
24/03/84 --> 24-03-1984
```

Based on various criteria (average length of human lifespan, when company has been around, ... ), I can assume what year `99` might refer to.

However, if I wanted to specify that `99` refers to `1899` or some other year ending in `99`, how would I do this?

I am reading over the docs for the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) patterns, as well as the explanations [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/field.html#centuryOfEra), and it looks like `CenturyOfEra` field `C` might be what I want to use, but it isn't obvious how I would use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it is referred as "Pivot Year": http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withPivotYear%28int%29

The CenturyOfEra is just our current century - XXI, the one which so many sci-fi authors dreamed about few decades back.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

By default, 2000 is used as the base value for the year. You can change this behaviour by specifying the base value for the year in the following [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendValueReduced-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-int-int-int-):

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder appendValueReduced(TemporalField field,
                                                   int width,
                                                   int maxWidth,
                                                   int baseValue)
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("01/30/14", dateTimeFormatterWithBaseYear("M/d/", 1900, null)));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("30/01/14", dateTimeFormatterWithBaseYear("d/M/", 1800, Locale.ENGLISH)));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("1/30/14", dateTimeFormatterWithBaseYear("M/d/", 1800, null)));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("30/1/14", dateTimeFormatterWithBaseYear("d/M/", 1700, Locale.ENGLISH)));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("01/30/1914", dateTimeFormatterWithBaseYear("M/d/", 1900, null)));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("30/01/2014", dateTimeFormatterWithBaseYear("d/M/", 1800, Locale.ENGLISH)));
    }

    public static DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatterWithBaseYear(String dayMonPattern, int baseYear, Locale locale) {
        return new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern(dayMonPattern)
                .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 4, baseYear)
                .toFormatter(locale == null ? Locale.getDefault() : locale);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1914-01-30
1814-01-30
1814-01-30
1714-01-30
1914-01-30
2014-01-30
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>